# Java: jersey jax-rs . Create custom query

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Java webservice that use jax-rs.
I need to create a query through a petition. I use this to get full value from a table

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<EstadoDia> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

Or use this to get the values  by  id.

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public EstadoDia find(@PathParam("id") PathSegment id) {
    net.gleegoo.es.EstadoDiaPK key = getPrimaryKey(id);
    return super.find(key);
}
```

My table example: EstadoDia

```
|ID  | day |hour   |send|
 1   |  17 |  22:00|true
 2   |  18 |  20:00|true
 3   |  19 |  20:35|true
 4   |  19 |  20:20|false
```

how to get all values of send ?

Comment: What do you want the response to look like? A JSON array of booleans? A JSON array of JSON object with only the "id" and "send" fields; or just the "send" fields?

Comment: Actually I just want to send average.
I imagine it would be better to send a text / plain

Comment: What problem are you having sending it? It would probably be a better idea just to give it it's own endpoint. It has nothing to do with the actual resource. It's a completely different resource. The actual collection is a totally different concept from the an average of some values. Makes sense to be it's own resource doesn't it?

Comment: My problem is: I can not do a query for all values of a row and return the average, for example.

Comment: There are sql (assuming your using an sql db) queries for that. Even nosql dbs should be able to get that average. The point I'm getting at is that getting an average should be it's own resource. Get the average from the db query